# Unmet dependencies while install grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am pulling my hair out. Have been unable to install grunt for like an hour.

I keep getting this:

```
npm WARN unmet dependency    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/tar-fs/node_modules/pump/node_modules/end-of-stream requires once@'~1.3.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/tar-fs/node_modules/pump/node_modules/once,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.2.0
```

please help

Comment: does it fail? these are just warnings they usually dont make the entire installation fail

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the cache and updating npm :

```
npm cache clean
npm update
```

This solved my problem